# Use of @objc inference in Swift 4

Tags: swift, selector, swift4

I am getting this warning:

> Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method
>   'customButtonDidTouch()' in 'CustomTableViewController' that depends
>   on '@objc' attribute inference deprecated in Swift 4

Xcode suggests adding `@objc` to my `customButtonDidTouch()` method, but doing so yields this other warning:

> The use of Swift 3 @objc inference in Swift 4 mode is deprecated.
>   Please address deprecated @objc inference warnings, test your code
>   with “Use of deprecated Swift 3 @objc inference” logging enabled, and
>   disable Swift 3 @objc inference.

Any suggestions?